# Modifying the file jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js to rewrite _draw function, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I am doing a gallery based on fancybox - actually I have modified to field to achieve what I need, and I've done it, the last issue I found is in this part of the code:

```
} else {
        fx.prop = 0;

        $(fx).animate({prop: 1}, {
            duration : currentOpts.changeSpeed,
            step : _draw,
            complete : finish_resizing
        });
```

The Draw function is here so you can see:

```
_draw = function(pos) {
            var dim = {
                width : parseInt(start_pos.width + (final_pos.width - start_pos.width) * pos, 10),
                height : parseInt(start_pos.height + (final_pos.height - start_pos.height) * pos, 10),

                top : parseInt(final_pos.top, 10),
                left : parseInt(final_pos.width, 10)
            };

            if (typeof final_pos.opacity !== 'undefined') {
                dim.opacity = pos < 0.8 ? 0.8 : pos;
            }

            wrap.css(dim);

            content.css({
                'width' : limit.width - currentOpts.padding * 2,
                'height' : limit.height - (titleHeight * pos) - currentOpts.padding * 2
            });
        },
```

My question  is how to modify the `_draw` function, or how to set a animate function, for **NEXT** and for **PREV**. Also disable opacity.

I need something like a "scrollable" function.. on the main image of Fancybox (kind of like this http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/)

So I just can't manage to get this done..

Is there other way from the fancybox options? because I can't find them.

Anyway, this was the original file -
**http://demo-store.prestashop.com/js/jquery/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js**

These are the changes I made on `line 663`:

```
_draw = function(pos) {
            var dim = {
                width : parseInt(start_pos.width + (final_pos.width - start_pos.width) * pos, 10),
                height : parseInt(start_pos.height + (final_pos.height - start_pos.height) * pos, 10),

                top : parseInt(final_pos.top, 10),
                left : parseInt(final_pos.width, 10)
            };

            if (typeof final_pos.opacity !== 'undefined') {
                dim.opacity = pos < 0.8 ? 0.8 : pos;
            }
```

And also this (but I don't think this affects it):

```
$('body').append(
        tmp = $('<div id="fancybox-tmp"></div>'),
        loading = $('<div id="fancybox-loading"><div></div></div>'),
        overlay = $('<div id="fancybox-overlay"></div>'),
        limit = $('<div id="limit"></div>')             
);

wraplimit = $('<div id="wraplimit"></div>').append( limit ).appendTo('body');           
thebox = $('<div id="thebox"></div>').append('<div id="comrigtt"></div>').appendTo( overlay )    
wrap = $('<div id="fancybox-wrap"></div>').append().appendTo( limit );

outer = $('<div id="fancybox-outer"></div>')
.append('<div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-n"></div><div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-ne"></div><div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-e"></div><div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-se"></div><div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-s"></div><div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-sw"></div><div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-w"></div><div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-nw"></div>')
.appendTo( wrap );
```

Comment: Editing open source files is not a good way to achieve something. These files are written by lots of developers and I think they know something.

Comment: Avoid doing this as Ahmet says. Did you try the version 2? You can post this here: GitHub https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues

Comment: Sounds easy but i have write a lot of other stuff that works arround this file and =( it would be and incredible ammount of work, i hope this is not the real solution.. Maybe if someone can tell me how to achieve this on fancybox2 (http://jsfiddle.net/s6TGs/5/) The problem on this example ( i made with jquerytools, is i cant insert a prev or next button to scroll the main image, almost the same problem i have here. =(, Saludos Tío que bonito es el Español

Comment: @AhmetCanGüven - I'd have to disagree with the recommendation to not modify.  That level of closed minded thought is not what got those "lots of developers" to be at the level of writing plugins...  If you'd like to argue that it might make your project less maintainable then great, but don't spread ignorance and the "black box open source project" myth.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to add custom animations for next and prev that differ from the main animation?  Have you checked the docs for http://fancybox.net/api and utilize the next and prev commands...

If what you want is the effet you posted in the fiddle then I would suggest the following nasty hack, (or drop fancybox and grab one that supports that effect out of the box).

1) enable fancybox on your trigger
2) use jQuery or other to create your thumbnails in a div and then append that div to the bottom of the created fancybox elements (down at the bottom  of body)
3) wire up your created thumbnails to use the existing fancybox api for next/prev/ specific etc.
4) avoid having to touch the js itself.